# How to loop mysql query on perl with date range

Tags: mysql, arrays, perl, loops, date

Is it possible to loop the query by range of dates?

START DATE: table_19910101

END DATE: table_19910131

```
sub verify {

    &db_connect();

    print "Trigger count 19910101: \n";
    $QRY = "SELECT trigger,count(1) FROM table_19910101 
            WHERE trigger IN ('B1','B2');";
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($QRY);
    $sth->execute();
    my $trigger = $sth->fetchall_arrayref();
    foreach my $row (@$trigger) {
        print join(" ", @$row), "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want to fetch all the data in one query you COULD premake all the different queries and then [UNION](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) them together into one call

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you're just looking for tables from a single month makes this easier.

```
foreach (19910101 .. 19911031) {
  say $_;
}
```

If you were going over a month boundary, then the range operator would start to generate invalid dates.

Your subroutine uses a variable (`$dbh`) which it doesn't declare. That's bad programming practice. I suspect that the variable is created as a global in `db_connect()`. It would be a far better idea to return the handle from that subroutine.

```
my $dbh = db_connect();
```

Also, please remove the `&` from subroutine calls. It generally hasn't been needed since Perl 5 was released in 1994.